# Initialize swift/swiftui var with 3 conditions

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to initialize a var with a couple of conditions

```
struct BreadCrumbCard: View { 
    var selection:String 
    var isSelected: Bool 

    var color = Color("Gray")

    if(isSelected){ //error is here
        color = Color("Yellow")
    }else if(!selection.isEmpty){
        color = Color("Green")
    }else{
        color = Color("Gray")
    }

    var body: some View{
      ...
```

> "Expected declaration"

I've been searching for some time now but I can't find a way to do this or an alternative, I'm sure this must be obvious but I am new to swift. How can I initialize this variable with these conditions?

Comment: Needed more context with shown what are those condition variables are.

Comment: not sure how that is relevant but I added it

Comment: You can do it in `onAppear`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't put control code in a struct's or class's top-level scope, it must always be placed inside a function or similar context.

There's several ways to solve this problem, one way would be to use a computed property:

```
struct BreadCrumbCard: View { 
    var selection: String 
    var isSelected: Bool 

    var color: Color {
        if isSelected { //error is here
            return Color("Yellow")
        } else if !selection.isEmpty {
            return Color("Green")
        } else {
            return Color("Gray")
        }
    }

    var body: some View{
      Text("foo").foregroundColor(self.color)
    }
}
```